# Resize child view controller without constraints (Auto Layout) in a container view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontainerview

I want to use container view with two child view controllers. But the problem is that when I update the child view controllers frame with the code below, the below part of the child view controller is not visible.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    firstVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstViewController"];
    secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
}

- (void)removeViewController
{
    [currentVC.view removeFromSuperview];
    [currentVC removeFromParentViewController];
}

- (void)bindToViewController:(UIViewController *)targetVC
{
    if (currentVC != nil)
    {
        [self removeViewController];
    }

    [self addChildViewController:targetVC];
    targetVC.view.frame = self.containerView.frame;
    [self.containerView addSubview:targetVC.view];
    currentVC = targetVC;
}

- (IBAction)firstOpen:(id)sender
{
    [self bindToViewController:firstVC];
}

- (IBAction)secondOpen:(id)sender
{
    [self bindToViewController:secondVC];
}

@end
```

There are solutions with constraints but my project storyboard doesn't use Auto Layout (constraints). 
Is there any opinion about my problem's solution? 

(Maybe I have to find another design way without using container view)

****** EDIT 1 ******

I added **didMoveToParentViewController** at the end of the bindToViewController but no change.

```
- (void)bindToViewController:(UIViewController *)targetVC
{
    if (currentVC != nil)
    {
        [self removeViewController];
    }

    [self addChildViewController:targetVC];
    targetVC.view.frame = self.containerView.frame;
    [self.containerView addSubview:targetVC.view];
    currentVC = targetVC;
    [targetVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

****** EDIT 2 - Solution ******

Tried **André Slotta**'s suggestion, it worked!

```
- (void)bindToViewController:(UIViewController *)targetVC
{
    if (currentVC != nil)
    {
        [self removeViewController];
    }

    [self addChildViewController:targetVC];
//    targetVC.view.frame = self.containerView.frame;
    targetVC.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
    [self.containerView addSubview:targetVC.view];
    currentVC = targetVC;
}
```

Comment: I doubt it will solve your issue, but you should also call `[targetVC didMoveToParentViewController:self]` at the end of your `bindToViewController:` method. Related docs : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmovetoparentviewcontroller

Comment: I edited my question with your offer, but no change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to be `targetVC.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;` instead of `targetVC.view.frame = self.containerView.frame;`.

Comment: Could you show a bit more of your UI setup and maybe a screenshot of the actual problem?

Comment: Thank you, it worked. (I'd given a wrong height value to the container view in the storyboard in my first try, after fixing it, your answer solved my issue.)

Comment: Perfect Solution!!